# wordpress pagination not worked into custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination, custom-post-type, categories

i added new custom post type in wordpress it name ( `add_series` )
it have posts for specific `category` 
for example ( series_cat1 & series_cat2 & series_cat3 & ... etc )  
but the noraml posts -> for articles have specific `category` else for example ( film_cat1 & film_cat2 & film_cat3 & ... etc ) 
now i made template to `category.php` and but into it **pagination** the `WP_Query`

```
$paged  =  get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;                

$category_posts_args =  array(

    'post_type'      => array('post','add_series'),
    'cat'            => $category_id,
    'paged'          => $paged                    

);                

$get_post_posts       = new WP_Query($category_posts_args);
```

to get posts from `post` and the custom post type `add_series` , from specific category ID -> i get the category id from the `current link`

now when i get into the links : 
`http://example.com/category/film_cat1/` OR `http://example.com/category/film_cat2/` OR `http://example.com/category/film_cat3/` the pagination work perfect
like `http://example.com/category/film_cat1/page/1` OR `http://example.com/category/film_cat1/page/2`

**But** the big problem into custom post type `add_series`
when i get into the links : 
`http://example.com/category/series_cat1/` OR `http://example.com/category/series_cat2/` OR 
`http://example.com/category/series_cat3/` the pagination is disappears
and when i get into 
`http://example.com/category/series_cat1/page/2` it redirect me to 404 not found page

**the problem** when i get into category url to see posts posted into `add_series` it disappear although *add_series* have posts into database and this posts have categories `series_cat1 & series_cat2 && series_.. etc )`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Your working URL will be "http://example.com/series_cat3/" because you haven't set taxonomy for your "series_" categories.

Comment: no categories `film_cat1 OR film_cat2 OR series_cat1 Or series_cat2` the all added into `category` defualt taxonomy ,,, but the categories `film_` i select it in defualt post type `post` and categories `series_` i select it in the new custom post type `add_series` but the pagination work and appear the paginate when i get `film_` category => post |||| but when i get `series_` category  => add_series it disappear